# How can I find what is preventing a fast forward merge?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-tag, fast-forward

We are doing Git Flow here, but now we need to create a hotfix branch from before Git Flow started. We have a `v906b03` tag from before the creation of `release` and `develop` branches. We also have `v914` and `v915` tags from after Git Flow started.

The approach would be some in this lines:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard v906b03 #make sure that master "passed by" v906b03
$ git branch v906b03-hotfix
$ git merge v914 #this merge should be a fast-forward
$ git merge v915 #this merge should be a fast-forward
```

Now, what I am getting is recursive merges for the merge with `v914`. I tried to find what `v906b03` commits aren't reachable from `v914` without luck.
I tried `git log --oneline --not v914 v906b03`, but it was empty.
I also tried `git log --oneline v914..v906b03`, that should be the same, also empty.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the default behavior for merging tags is to use `--no-ff` as a merge option

That won't be the case anymore with Git 2.17 (Q2 2018)

See [commit adcc94a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/adcc94a0aa7055be4133ebda8b25f4af63285c6d) (14 Feb 2018) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f88590e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f88590e67580572acd9c2f61fe4d652b9b2c779d), 06 Mar 2018)</sup>

> ### `merge`: allow fast-forward when merging a tracked tag
>
> Long time ago at [fab47d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fab47d057559301c74d6642576694fd251a3fd11) ("merge: force edit and no-ff mode when
>   merging a tag object", 2011-11-07, Git v1.7.9-rc0), "`git merge`" was made to always create a merge commit when merging a tag, even when the side branch
>   being merged is a descendant of the current branch.
>
> This default is good for merges made by upstream maintainers to
>   integrate work signed by downstream contributors, but will leave
>   pointless `no-ff` merges when downstream contributors pull a newer
>   release tag to make their long-running topic branches catch up with
>   the upstream.
>   When there is no local work left on the topic, such a merge should simply fast-forward to the commit pointed at by the release tag.
>
> Update the default (again) for "`git merge`" that merges a tag object
>   to
>
> - (1) `--no-ff` (i.e. create a merge commit even when side branch
>     fast forwards) if the tag being merged is not at its expected place
>     in `refs/tags/` hierarchy and
> - (2) `--ff` (i.e. allow fast-forward update when able) otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I found a reference on http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-merge-lt-tag-gt-behavior-td7580058.html stating that the default behavior for merging tags is to use `--no-ff` as a merge option.
I even tried using `--ff` without success, but using the commit hash or even `git show-ref <tag>` would do the trick.

Comment: That won't be the case with Git 2.17 (Q2 2018): see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49215680/6309). So your initial issue might not be an issue anymore with Git 2.17.

Answer (score 0):

If merging from v906b03 to v914 and v915 is just a fast-forward, then you can create your v906b03-hotfix at the v915 right away and not merge at all.

Also why do you move your master to v906b03? (reset --hard)

Comment: I wanted to prove just that to a colleague of mine. That branching on the v906b03 would be exactly the same.

Comment: @Spidey Can you provide some graph with all this tags and branches to better understand what's going on in your repo?